# Ember Data delete fails, how to rollback

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

If I call destroyRecord and it fails on the server, it also disappears from the local store and from the UI.  I need to somehow "rollback" if delete fails.  I have tried something like this.

```
        item.destroyRecord().then(function () {
            Notify.success("item removed");
        }).catch(function (response) {
            //NEED TO ROLLBACK HERE - ANY IDEAS?
            Notify.error('Failed to remove!');
        });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, rollback with relationships doesn't fully work in ember data, secondly the newer versions of ember data handle this better (ember data 1.0 beta 7+).  Records have a rollback method on them for this very purpose, it's still in beta, but it does mostly what you're looking for.

```
    item.destroyRecord().then(function () {
        Notify.success("item removed");
    }).catch(function (response) {
        item.rollback();
        Notify.error('Failed to remove!');
    });
```

**NOTE:** In newer versions of Ember, `item.rollback()` no longer functions, instead use `item.rollbackAttributes()` as mentioned in comments from Marcelo.

Comment: It worked!!!  Weird, because I tried it earlier and it didn't work - it must have been something else.  Thanks.

Comment: I just tried it again and it was working.  Would you mind creating a new question and writing all of your specifics (It seems easier than me asking a dozen questions in these comments)

Comment: let me ask you first, what do you return from the server to trigger the catch?

Comment: i see, i did the same, and when i try to rollback i get Error: Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object. I'll create a new question

Comment: here is my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416905/getting-error-assertion-failed-calling-set-on-destroyed-object-when-trying-to

Comment: `item.rollback()` works for me if the server returns a 400, but fails if the server returns a 422.  Not sure why, but this may be helpful in debugging...