# Getting "Error: Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object" when trying to rollback a deletion

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am looking into how to show proper deletion error message in ember when there is an error coming back from the server. I looked at this topic and followed its suggestion:
[Ember Data delete fails, how to rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937976/ember-data-delete-fails-how-to-rollback)

My code is just like it, I return a 400 and my catch fires and logs, but nothing happens, when I pause it in the debugger though and try to rollback, I get Error: Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object

So A) I cannot rollback B) the error is eaten normally.

Here is my code

```
visitor.destroyRecord().then(function() {
                    console.log('SUCCESS');
                }).catch(function(response) {
                    console.log('failed to remove', response);
                    visitor.rollback();                        
                });
```

In case it's relevant, my model does have multiple relationships. What am I doing wrong? Ember-data version is 1.0.0.8 beta (previous one from the release a few days ago).

Thanks in advance.

*EDIT*

I discovered now that the record actually is restored currently inside the cache according to ember inspector, but the object will not reappear in the rendering of the visitors. I need some way to force it to reload into the template...

Answer (score 1):

After `destroyRecord`, the record is gone and the deletion cannot be rolled back. The `catch` clause will just catch a server error. If you want the record back, and think it's still on the server, you'll have to reload it.

See the following comment on `deleteRecord` from the Ember Data source:

> ```
> Marks the record as deleted but does not save it. You must call
> `save` afterwards if you want to persist it. You might use this
> method if you want to allow the user to still `rollback()` a
> delete after it was made.
> ```

This implies that a rollback after save is *not* possible. There is also no sign anywhere I can see in the Ember Data code for somehow reverting a record deletion when the DELETE request fails.

In theory you might be able to muck with the `isDeleted` flag, or override various internal hooks, but I'd recommend against that unless you really know how things work.

Comment: hmm that's rather inconvenient, i wonder why ember-data won't destroy it after a successful response... I was told it can.

Comment: So, this means I need to call `deleteRecord()`, make an ajax request to my DELETE route, then call `save()` if my DELETE was successful?

Comment: Not exactly. It means you should ensure your server can successfully handle the `DELETE` request, then call `destroyRecord` or `deleteRecord` and then `save`. If the server delete succeeds, all is well; if it fails for some reason, then you need to handle that in some reasonable way, which might or might not be reloading the record from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Try reloading the model after the rollback. It will reload from the server but it was the only way around this that I could find.

```
visitor.destroyRecord().then(function() {
                console.log('SUCCESS');
            }).catch(function(response) {
                console.log('failed to remove', response);
                visitor.rollback();
                visitor.reload().then(function(vis)
                {
                    console.log('visitor.reload :: ' + JSON.stringify(vis));
                });
            });
```

Hope that helps.